# Is there a cleaner way to do an if else statement in a AngularJS html view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

Here is the code I have:

```
<td ng-repeat="header in vm.headers">
    <span ng-if="header.key !='location'">
        {{ row[header.key] }}
    </span>
    <span ng-if = "header.key =='location'">
        {{ row[header.key].siteName }}
    </span>
</td>
```

feel like there might be a cleaner way to do this in angular "*Js 1.5.5**

I saw the following example on a highly rated SO post,but I dont really understand it. The code they showed was the following

```
<div>{{ConditionVar ? 'varIsTrue' : 'varIsFalse'}}</div>
```

Can anyone show me how to convert my two ng-if statements to the example above, or a better example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
{{ row[header.key] === 'location' ? row[header.key].siteName : row[header.key] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way to do  if-else is using `ngSwitch`. I hope it will work.

```
<div ng-switch="header.key">
   <span ng-switch-when="!location">
                {{ row[header.key] }}
  </span>
  <span ng-switch-when="location">
                {{ row[header.key].siteName }}
  </span>
```

Comment: Both `ng-if` and `ng-switch` create new inherited scopes. For an Angular expression as small as this example, the ternary operator uses a lot less overhead.